# Efeito hover em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos-do-mouse, css-hover

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte: quero que quando o usuário passe o mouse em determinada imagem um outro local ganhe uma classe para que eu possa a estilizar, poderiam me ajudar?

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
var $JQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery2(function() {
    $JQuery2(".bt_pagamento-facilitado").hover(function(){
                $JQuery2(".bt_criacoes-exclusivas").addClass("redesAl");
    });
});
```

Comment: Você poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268527/edit) e colocar alguma informação sobre o erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Simplesmente nada acontece, acredito que esta certo a logica, porém não funciona.

Comment: @Fernando, a classe não é adicionada?

Comment: Tem certeza que não da para fazer com CSS? Poste o html/css que ajuda

Answer (score 4):

O evento [`.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) deve ter 2 funções: uma para quando o mouse estiver sobre o elemento e outra para quando sair.

```js
var $JQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery2(function() {
   $JQuery2(".bt_pagamento-facilitado").hover(
      // função que adiciona a classe
      function(){
         $JQuery2(".bt_criacoes-exclusivas").addClass("redesAl");
      },
      // função que remove a classe
      function(){
         $JQuery2(".bt_criacoes-exclusivas").removeClass("redesAl");
      });
});
```

```css
.redesAl {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Passe o mouse sobre a imagem:
<br />
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" height="50" class="bt_pagamento-facilitado" />
<br />
<div class="bt_criacoes-exclusivas">Texto texto</div>
```

**[Documentação oficial do `.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)**.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fernando Fico feliz! Se puder, marque a resposta com ✓. Obg!

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção diferente para o problema é fazer esse efeito direto com CSS usando alguns [seletores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletores_CSS), que podem ser:

```
.classe ~ .outraClasse {} #se outraClasse é irmao de classe
.classe + .outraClasse {} #se outraClasse é o proximo elemento
.classe > .outraClasse {} #se outraClasse está direto dentro de classe
.classe ~ .outraClasse {} #se outraClasse está em algum lugar dentro de classe
```

**Exemplo**

```css
#imagem {
  background-color: red;
}

#imagem:hover + #alterar {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img alt="Imagem vem aqui" id="imagem" />

  <div id="alterar">
    <h4>Conteudo da div</h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: +1 por usar somente css. contudo acredito q só funcione enquanto ocorre o hover certo? pois ao remover o mouse não há o efeito

Comment: Seria basicamente isso mesmo que eu preciso, tentei adaptar mas não funcionou : #imgPagFaci:hover + #bt_criacoes-exclusivas {
    right: 500px;
}

Comment: Bom ponto @N.Dias, caso o estilo seja permanente após o hover não vai funcionar

Comment: Duas coisas @Fernando, precisamos saber a parte relevante do seu HTML e evento hover deverá mudar permanentemente o outro elemento, ou quando sair o mouse retira a alteração?

Comment: Quando o efeito hover passar as informações voltam como eram antes

Comment: Como assim um estilo permanente? Esse atributo do right já foi preenchido com um valor, quero que ele mude com esse hover

Comment: Então dessa forma é a mais indicada, por ficar somente no css. Talvez não esteja aplicando por nomes das classes..varios outros motivos. Estilo permanente se apos a alteração do hover, o elemento alterado não mudará mais ou se voltará ao estado anterior

Comment: Testando dessa forma ele simplesmente não obedece a primeira instrução de ganhar esse valor somente após o hover, simplesmente ele pega o valor que era pra ser atribuído so depois do hover: div#bt_criacoes-exclusivas:hover+#bt_pagamento-facilitado {
    right: 500px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Veja seu código funcionando...

```js
var $JQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery2(function() {
    $JQuery2(".bt_pagamento-facilitado").hover(function(){
                $JQuery2(".bt_criacoes-exclusivas").addClass("redesAl");
    });
});
```

```css
.bt_pagamento-facilitado {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.bt_criacoes-exclusivas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.redesAl {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bt_pagamento-facilitado"></div>

<div class="bt_criacoes-exclusivas"></div>
```

Talvez você não definiu direito as classes no HTML ou no CSS...

Comment: Mas quando eu tirar o mouse o efeito deve voltar ao normal